# Facebook not load gif animated

Tags: facebook, animation, gif

I have a gif: https://lactroi.me/uploads/2017/07/zlIyOmCdGFv.gif

And share it on Facebook. But it not show animated.

Then I using debug tool. And click Scrape Again many time then it work.

How I can share gif to facebook and it load animated on first time.

You can see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qohRHUOi1k

Comment: How are you sharing the GIF. Can you add some code? I have had similar issues with the Facebook php share dialog, which might be what you used?

Comment: The link to the gif doesn't work anymore. If you figured out the answer, please post your own answer. If you can't share the GIF anymore, please consider closing the question. It may depend on the file size of the GIF (there's a max file size). It may depend on a lot of other issues. Without the GIF, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading through an API Call, upload it under "videos" category.